# sorted in order of decreasing frequency

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I want to be able to show the output in sorted in order of decreasing frequency. If two or more codons have the same frequency, the script should break the tie using the alphabetical order of the codons. In this example, cag and gtt each occur just once, but because c precedes g, cag comes before gtt above.

when I run my script

```
cat test
aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt
./histogram test
3 aac 
1 gtt 
2 tgt 
1 cag
```

but instead, I want to be able to do

```
./histogram test
3 aac

2 tgt

1 cag

1 gtt
```

Here what I did

```
declare -a codons=(aac gtt tgt cag)

for items in  ${codons[@]}
do

        count=$( grep -o $items $1  | sort  -k1,1nr -k2,2 | wc -l)

     # count=$( grep -o $items $1 | uniq -c | wc -l | sort  -k1,1nr -k2,2  )
        echo "$count $items "
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the output.

```
./histogram test | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2
```

If you want to include the `sort` into your script you can append it after the `done` of your loop:

```
...
done | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2
```

By the way: `sort | wc -l` is wasted time, since `sort` does not change the number of lines. Just use `wc -l`.

For your example output of `./histogram test` [this should print](https://onlinegdb.com/rk9-crTNu)

```
3 aac
2 tgt
1 cag
1 gtt
```

Comment: only files as an arguments but I am not supposed to pass any other arguments or command in the command line